# AWS Data Pipeline restore to DynamoDB table error with "is in status 'CANCELLED' with reason 'Job terminated' "

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I have configured a AWS Data Pipeline to export a DynamoDB table to a S3 bucket (using the template) in a different account. That export is working just fine, but I have some issues when I try to restore the backup into the new table in that second account (Using the import template too).

My source of information for this task: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-pipeline-account-access-dynamodb-s3/

1. I can see that the AWS Data Pipeline is restoring data to the new table (not sure if all the data is being restored) however the execution has status `CANCELED`.
2. The activity log shows several times this: `EMR job '@TableLoadActivity_2020-09-07T12:45:59_Attempt=1' with jobFlowId 'j-11620944P11II' is in  status 'WAITING' and reason 'Cluster ready after last step completed.'. Step 'df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@TableLoadActivity_2020-09-07T12:45:59_Attempt=1' is in status 'RUNNING' with reason 'null'`,

2.a) then the canceled part `EMR job '@TableLoadActivity_2020-09-07T12:45:59_Attempt=1' with jobFlowId 'j-11620944P11II' is in  status 'WAITING' and reason 'Cluster ready after last step completed.'. Step 'df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@TableLoadActivity_2020-09-07T12:45:59_Attempt=1' is in status 'CANCELLED' with reason 'Job terminated'`

See full log below (just left few lines with error on point #2):

```
07 Sep 2020 12:52:04,844 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller: Executing: amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.EmrActivity@1d0415c
07 Sep 2020 12:52:04,887 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.factory.S3ClientFactory: Returning cached AmazonS3Client for the region [eu-west-1]
07 Sep 2020 12:52:04,945 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.EmrActivity: EMR transform starting.
07 Sep 2020 12:52:04,957 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.cluster.EmrClient: EMR client waiting for cluster to enter ready state for jobflow id 'j-11620944P11II'.
07 Sep 2020 12:52:04,957 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.cluster.EmrClient: EMR client checking if cluster is ready for jobflow with id 'j-11620944P11II'.
07 Sep 2020 12:52:05,141 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.cluster.EmrClient: EMR client reports that cluster with jobflow id 'j-11620944P11II' is ready.
07 Sep 2020 12:52:05,200 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.cluster.EmrClient: EMR client adding steps with request '{JobFlowId: j-11620944P11II,Steps: [{Name: df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@TableLoadActivity_2020-09-07T12:45:59_Attempt=1,ActionOnFailure: CONTINUE,HadoopJarStep: {Properties: [],Jar: s3://dynamodb-dpl-eu-west-1/emr-ddb-storage-handler/4.11.0/emr-dynamodb-tools-4.11.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar,Args: [org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDBImport, s3://dynamodb-backup-imported/2020-09-06-12-19-11/, blabla-test6, 0.25]}}]}'
07 Sep 2020 12:53:05,352 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.cluster.EmrUtil: EMR job '@TableLoadActivity_2020-09-07T12:45:59_Attempt=1' with jobFlowId 'j-11620944P11II' is in  status 'WAITING' and reason 'Cluster ready after last step completed.'. Step 'df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@TableLoadActivity_2020-09-07T12:45:59_Attempt=1' is in status 'RUNNING' with reason 'null'
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,772 [WARN] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.cluster.EmrUtil: EMR job flow named 'df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59' with jobFlowId 'j-11620944P11II' is in status 'WAITING' because of the step 'df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@TableLoadActivity_2020-09-07T12:45:59_Attempt=1' failures 'Job terminated'
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,772 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.cluster.EmrUtil: EMR job '@TableLoadActivity_2020-09-07T12:45:59_Attempt=1' with jobFlowId 'j-11620944P11II' is in  status 'WAITING' and reason 'Cluster ready after last step completed.'. Step 'df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@TableLoadActivity_2020-09-07T12:45:59_Attempt=1' is in status 'CANCELLED' with reason 'Job terminated'
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,772 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.cluster.EmrUtil: Collecting steps stderr logs for cluster with AMI null
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,777 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.LogMessageUtil: Returning tail errorMsg :
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,777 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.cluster.EmrUtil: Collecting steps logs for cluster with AMI/ReleaseLabel emr-5.23.0
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,778 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.mapreduce.EMRActivityHelperFactory: Getting the helper for version 2.8.3
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,778 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.mapreduce.EMRActivityHelper: Uploading step log details
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,778 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.mapreduce.EMRActivityHelper: path to step logss3n://srh-data-export-int2/df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472/EmrClusterForLoad/@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59/@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59_Attempt=1/j-11620944P11II/steps
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,778 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.mapreduce.EMRActivityHelper: step log file /mnt/taskRunner/output/logs/df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472/TableLoadActivity/@TableLoadActivity_2020-09-07T12:45:59/@TableLoadActivity_2020-09-07T12:45:59_Attempt=1/hadoop.jobs.log
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,782 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.mapreduce.EMRActivityHelper: Done uploading hadoop log details
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,842 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.mapreduce.EMRActivityHelper: Field value updated 
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,842 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.mapreduce.EMRActivityHelper: Done updating the field with value 
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,844 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.HeartBeatService: Finished waiting for heartbeat thread @TableLoadActivity_2020-09-07T12:45:59_Attempt=1
07 Sep 2020 13:48:08,845 [INFO] (TaskRunnerService-df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472_@EmrClusterForLoad_2020-09-07T12:45:59-0) df-06812232H5PDR4VVK472 amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller: Work EmrActivity took 56:4 to complete
```

3. If I go to the dependency "EmrClusterForLoad" I see this:

```
@failureReason Resource timeout due to terminateAfter configuration
@status TIMEDOUT
```

[image]

4. My activity is the one on the image, and the step field has this config

```
s3://dynamodb-dpl-#{myDDBRegion}/emr-ddb-storage-handler/4.11.0/emr-dynamodb-tools-4.11.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar,org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDBImport,#{input.directoryPath},#{output.tableName},#{output.writeThroughputPercent}
```

[image]

5. Resources config:
   [image]

**I would like to understand what I am missing in here, and how I can solve it, or whether it is bug**, because I see some data in the new table, so the restore is at least partially ok, but this from the log: `status 'WAITING' and reason 'Cluster ready after last step completed` and then being canceled means that perhaps the restored is not fully completed.

Then I read somewhere that this error message `@failureReason Resource timeout due to terminateAfter configuration` is a matter of adding an optional field called `terminateAfter`, which is not available in my Architect view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWERING TO MYSELF**

The issue was that I set the `Terminate After` field because I got the warning message on the image below which suggested to do that, so I set `Terminate After` 1 hour and the reason I used that time is because the file to be imported was only `9,6 MB`. How much time does it need to process such as small file?.
[image]

So the import process of that small file last about 5 hours.

Findings:

To improve the import time I increased the `myDDBWriteThroughputRatio`value to 0.95 from 0.25, At the beginning I didn't touch that parameter because it was the default value from the template, and AWS documentation sometimes simplify a lot stuff that in many cases you have to discover by trial and error.

After changing that value the import last about an hour, which is way better that 5 hours but still slow, because we are talking about only `9,6 MB`
[image]

Then this that I saw in the logs `is in  status 'WAITING' and reason 'Cluster ready after last step completed.'` which worried me a bit due to I'm new to using this tool and I didn't quite get message, is simply the following as explained ny someone from AWS

*

> If you see that the EMR Cluster is in Waiting, Cluster ready after
> last steps, it means that cluster had executed the first request it
> has received and is waiting to execute the next request/activity on
> the cluster.

- 

These are all my findings, hopefully this will helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked after i changed the capacity to on demand.